# CMake handle target_link_directories() incorrectly with circular dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have circular dependencies between lib A and B:

```
add_library(B b.cpp)
add_library(A a.cpp)

target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC A)
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC B)

add_library(X x.cpp)
target_link_directories(X PUBLIC /jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj)
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC X)

add_executable(hello main.cxx)
target_link_libraries(hello PUBLIC A)
```

At link stage, CMake generate command:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.o -o hello  libA.a libB.a libA.a libB.a libX.a
```

The path from target_link_directories is missing.

But if I change the order of adding lib A and B, the result looks correct:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.o -o hello   -L/jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj  -Wl,-rpath,/jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj libA.a libB.a libA.a libB.a libX.a
```

Is this a CMake issue? How can I avoid this. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what change did you do to make it work please ?

Comment: My work around is avoiding using circular dependencies.

Comment: I think Martin means "what exactly do you mean by 'if I change the order of adding lib A and B'"? Can you show exactly what you change the order of and how the CMakeLists.txt looks like for the working version?